# nested loop in jinja2 and flask from sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm looping records from mysql using flask sqlachemy and I'm storing a list in task_languages in the db as 
["Python", "JavaScript", "Bash", "Ruby", "C", "Rust"]

I'm having issues looping the list from the db as a nested loop so I can style the list in html. For every character its adding a space, any ideas how to style fix this?

app.py

```
tasks = Tasks.query.filter(Tasks.task_id == "300")
```

I'm passing tasks into the jinja2 template and looping the task_languages

rendered.html

```
 {% for task in tasks %}
   <tr>  
    <td>
    {% for list in task.task_languages %}
    {{list}}
   {% endfor %}
    </td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

output

[ " P y t h o n " , " J a v a S c r i p t " , " B a s h " , " R u b y " , " C " , " R u s t " ]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your query. Normally, filtering on an ID, which I assume would give a unique result, would return a single record. is it now returning multiple records or returning a single record which in this case is a list?

Comment: It’s just pulling one record for testing, I was sick of the page filling up with all the records.

Comment: Sure, understandable. So the query you show above, does not result in the output list?

Comment: I'm basically trying to figure out store the data in the db. The above show spaces per character but when I pass the list into the template it works  e.g. 
'langs = ["Python", "JavaScript", "Bash", "Ruby", "C", "Rust"]'

 {% for lang in langs %}
  <li>{{ lang }}</li>
  {% endfor %}

Comment: Can you please show your sql model and how the languages are stored in db? Are you actually storing the list as a string in db maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question myself didn't think it would be this simple but it just need to be spill depending on how you have store the string - .split(',').

e.g.

```
{% for  list in task.task_languages.split(',') %}
                          <span class="label label-info">{{list}}</span>
                              {% endfor %}
```